# Avro schema from confluent schema registry for kafka-streams groupby (akka aggr) operation

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I use schema-registry for all my apps with Kafka Streams.
One of our flows makes aggregation and I want to use schema-registry for aggregated object as follows:

```
stream.groupByKey()
.windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.of(timeWindowDuration, chronoUnit)))
.aggregate(initAggreggatedObj(), aggregateData(), Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), avroSerde))
```

But when adding schema to schema-registry, we need to define schema by topic name. In case of aggregation on stream it's impossible, since topic name generated by stream topology.

The question is if there is some way to create schema per any topic to make possible to use by any flow or any other solution?

Comment: The AvroSerde default behavior is to register the schema upon producer serialization, so you don't need to pre-define schemas on the registry if you don't want to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx, [OneCricketeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/onecricketeer), your response is correct. There is `auto.register.schemas` parameter which is by default true